# Prove, by mathematical induction, a confusing answer

Tags: induction

The question is to prove (or disprove) by mathematical induction the following statement:

> For $ n, a, r, \in \mathbb Z,$ and $n, a, r \in  Z_{>0},$ and $r ≥ 2$ $$S(n) = \sum_{i=0}^n ar^{i-1} = an$$

The sample answer given by the book is this

$$S(2) = \sum_{i=0}^2 ar^{i-1} = a + ar = a(r+1)$$
$$≥ 3a\ (\text{ because }\ r≥2)$$
$$> 2a,\ S(2)\text{ is not true }$$

I don't understand how $S(2) = a + ar = a(r + 1)$?

Shouldn't it be $S(2) = a(2)$?

Comment: The statement is false, the sample answer gives a counter example. Are you sure it is not a prove/disprove question?

Comment: $i=0$ gives $r^{-1}$.

Comment: @PeldePinda Hi, sorry I missed that out. Already submitted an edit to include the disproving part. But I still don't understand, where does the `a + ar = a(r+1)` come from?

Comment: Should the lower index be $i=1$?

Answer (score 1):

The proposed formula is actually false.  Take $r=n$ (this would be a positive integer, so its good) and you will find that for $n>1$,

$$\sum_{i=0}^nar^{i-1}=\frac an+a+\color{blue}{an}+\dots+an^{n-1}>an$$

Comment: What's wrong with this simple answer?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this answer @Simply :).

Answer (score 1):

First we assume that the lower index is $i=1$ otherwise the question (and answer provided) doesn't quite make sense.

In this case, we are asked to prove that

$$S(n)=\sum_{i=1}^n ar^{i-1}=an$$
where $n,a,r\in \mathbb Z^+$ and $r\ge 2$.

This is basically the sum of a geometric progression (GP) and the closed form is clearly false for the general case unless $r=1$. As $r\ge 2$, hence the proposed statement is false.

The solution provided puts $n=2$ and evaluates the summation term by term (only $2$, so easily done by hand), i.e.
$$S(2)=\sum_{i=1}^2 ar^{i-1}=a+ar=a(r+1)\ge 3a\quad \text{(as }r\ge 2) \neq 2a $$
Hence proposition is false for $n=2$.

---

The correct solution, for $r\ge 2$ is
$$S(n)=\sum_{i=1}^n ar^{i-1}=\frac {a(r^{n-1}-1)}{r-1}$$